# How to get the namespace where a function is called?

Tags: php, namespaces

Is there a way to make this to work?

```
<?php

namespace Bar {
    class test {
        public function test($action) {
            call_user_func($action); // must call \Foo\Action
        }
    }
}

namespace Foo {
    $test = new \Bar\Test;

    function action () {
        echo 'it works!';
    }

    $test->test('action');
}
```

For a more detailed description: If I have a function that call user defined functions with de call_user_func, and uses that function in a Foo namespace to call a Foo namespaced function, how can I know that this passed function is on Foo namespace?

Answer (score 2):

If you pass a function around by name in a string, you always need to use the **fully qualified name** including namespace. `'action'` refers to the function `\action`. Even within the same namespace this won't work correctly. You need to use `'Foo\action'` under all circumstances.

If you don't like hardcoding the namespace name, use `__NAMESPACE__ . '\\action'`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the constant [`__NAMESPACE__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.nsconstants.php) and pass it as argument, e.g.

```
$test->test("\\" . __NAMESPACE__ . '\\action');
```

Comment: The leading ``\`` is superfluous and wrong. Passing by-name already implies *fully qualified* names.